# Floyd-Warshall STP implementation

Tags: c++

Im having a problem with the Floyd-Warshall Algorithm. It doesn't work if the input have more than 4 vertices. To make 2nd dimension dynamic array i make a dynamic array [N*N] and access A[i,j] = A[(i-1)*N+j]

```
void floyd_Algorithm(fstream &F2,int N,int matrixGraph[],int matrixP[])
{
for (int k=1; k<=N; k++)
    for (int i=1; i<=N; i++)
        for (int j=1; j<=N; j++)
        {
            if (matrixGraph[(i-1)*N+j] > matrixGraph[(i-1)*N+k] + matrixGraph[(k-1)*N+j])
            {
                matrixGraph[(i-1)*N+j] =  matrixGraph[(i-1)*N+k] + matrixGraph[(k-1)*N+j];
                matrixP[(i-1)*N+j] = k ;
            }
}
```

here is the input of 4 vertices matrix

4

0 10 6 2|
10 0 5 3|
6 5 0 1|
2 3 1 0|

output

0   5   3   2
5   0   4   3
3   4   0   1
2   3   1   0

1   4   4   1
4   2   4   2
4   4   3   3
4   4   4   4

7 vertices matrix input

7

0 3 6 0 0 0 0|
3 0 2 4 0 0 0|
6 2 0 1 4 2 0|
0 4 1 0 2 0 4|
0 0 4 2 0 2 1|
0 0 2 0 2 0 1|
0 0 0 4 1 1 0|

output

0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0

1   5   7   1   1   1   1
5   2   7   5   2   2   2
7   7   3   7   7   7   3
4   5   7   4   1   4   1
5   5   7   1   5   1   1
6   6   7   6   1   6   1
7   7   7   1   1   1   7

Comment: You didn't show the memory management code. Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'd also highly suggest you run your code with `valgrind` to check for memory issues.

Answer (score 2):

Something wrong with your indices.

If your vertices are in arngle of 1 <= v <= N, then path between i and j should be matrix[(i-1)*N+j-1]

To avoid mistake, you probably should keep vertices in range of 0 <= v < N, for (int i = 0; i < N; i++), matrix[i*N+j]

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void floyd_Algorithm(fstream &F2,int N,int matrixGraph[],int matrixP[])
{
for (int k=0; k<N; k++)
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            if (matrixGraph[i*N+j] > matrixGraph[i*N+k] + matrixGraph[k*N+j])
            {
                matrixGraph[i*N+j] =  matrixGraph[i*N+k] + matrixGraph[k*N+j];
                matrixP[i*N+j] = k ;
            }
}
cout << "Ma tran duong di ngan nhat sau khi xu ly :\n";
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    cout <<"\n";
    for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
        cout << matrixGraph[i*N+j] <<"   ";
}
cout << "\nMa tran luu dinh sau khi xu ly :\n";
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    cout <<"\n";
    for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
        cout << matrixP[i*N+j] <<"   ";
}
}
void dijkstra_Algorithm(fstream &F2,int N,int matrixGraph[],int matrixP[])
{

}
int main()
{
int n,t,c;
fstream f1,f2;
f1.open("D:\\Input3.INP",ios::in);
f2.open("D:\\Output3.OUT",ios::out);
f1 >> n;
int matrix_graph[n*n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        f1 >> matrix_graph[i*n+j];
    }
int matrix_p[n*n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        matrix_p[i*n+j] = i;
    }
cout << "Hay nhap thuat toan muon su dung :\n";
cout << "1 : Floyd-Warshall Algorithm\n";
cout << "2 : Dijkstra Algorithm\n";
while ((t!=1)&&(t!=2))
{
    cout << "Enter : ";
    cin >> t;
}
cout << "Ma tran trong so da nhap la :\n";
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    cout <<"\n";
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        cout << matrix_graph[i*n+j] <<"   ";
}
cout << "\n";
switch (t)
{
case 1 :
    floyd_Algorithm(f2,n,matrix_graph,matrix_p);
    break;
case 2 :
    dijkstra_Algorithm(f2,n,matrix_graph,matrix_p);
    break;
}
return 0;
}
```

My complete code here, changing the indices still making same result